# Vue.js(CLI): Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '***'

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I run `vue-cli-service build` and everything is fine.

But if I run `vue-cli-service build --mode development` -
 I get the error message:

> Error: Can't resolve '/home/nik/DEV/my/blackchaose.vuejs_tpl/development' in '/home/nik/DEV/my/blackchaose.vuejs_tpl'

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

And how else can I run the assembly in Development mode?

p.s. I already have a `.env.local` file in the root directory with the following contents: `NODE_ENV = development`

Answer (score 4):

This is a slightly different issue, but I was running into this problem when deploying the site via a Github workflow. The problem was that we had `- run: npm run build --mode development` which caused the error about being unable to resolve the entry module.

The fix was to add a new build script into `package.json` under `scripts` like this: `"build-dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development"` and then to reference that new build script from the workflows .yml file like so: `- run: npm run build-dev`

Comment: that one worked, You are savior man :) , its strange that its same command in fact, works if in package.json but not directly in cmd, maybe because I am on windows ?

Answer (score 0):

With NODE_ENV set to develpment, you can assemble and run your project with `vue-cli-service serve`

See the vue-cli docs for more information on different modes:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: Thanks! I will see the link later again. But I did not see how to build a project with the Development Environment and without starting a local server...